# Prevent SharePoint from changing URLs in Static Pages

Tags: 2013, page-layout

Recently, I have noticed that SharePoint is changing URLs in static pages.  When a user moves or renames a file, SharePoint updates the URL.  I need to turn this functionality off; at least for the Library with the custom pages.  Can anyone tell me how to turn it off?

example: Splash.aspx is in the Pages directory.  On Splash.aspx, I have a link to "/documents/test.txt".  I go to the Documents Library and I change the name of "test.txt" to "NewName.txt".  Without editing Splash.aspx, the link is now pointing to "/documents/NewName.txt".  I need the link to stay "/documents/test.txt", even if the file is renamed or moved..

Comment: Can you provide examples of what kind of changes in URLs you are experiencing? This doesn't sound like a normal behavior, which loosely suggests about a custom solution causing the behavior, or, a non-suggested approach to refer to the URL.

Comment: It is pages library?

Comment: jpussacq, it is in the Pages Library.

Comment: moe,  I added an example.